# Success response when injecting a transaction with outdated branch

Tags: node, operation, inject

*Action*: Publish a Operation through the Node RPC which references a branch/block that is older than allowed.

*Observed Behavior*: Node returns Operation Id, Operation gets published to mempool successfully but will immediately be rendered invalid.

*Expected Behavior*: Node returns error message, Operation not spread to network.

*Use Case*: Integrated Wallet system which would need to know whether the publishing of the transaction was successful. It is understood that just publishing does not guarantee inclusion but if it is known that the transaction will never be valid, it would be nice to get an error.

Is this expected behavior or a bug? Thinking outside our system it seems that it can also be used to spam Tezos nodes since they will store transactions which will never cost anybody anything, since they are invalid.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bug. I've created an issue [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/800) and we will investigate it further.

It would be helpful if you could post an example transaction that triggers this to make it easier to reproduce.

Comment: This raw transaction for example:
7da046cf69e9b94cbd21409c982163ec26d53972c8e1b1790e3ba343051143826c012cb2ade0f1fc3da5ef66490646e5f95e473e407cb817f89f8902845200904e00015f570d0cd26b0c12714641b54075fcdab37905de003390d2d4e6ee4f4d7c2184b162988d406163d28cead77c67086f3336562a520f74af1ec99eb9ed61ad48ef2ce4b8596863a6354388834a4cfb2cd547698db47f

Deployed just now, many hours after creation with success response and picked up by mempool: https://tzkt.io/ooeH722XsiQxyVenYKhLuUzneUNKRLrmnc7W4m96PdZCR7ZzrpF